# how to install asp.net kigg starter kit?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kigg

I am trying to install kigg starter kit on my local machine.

I download the KiGG v3.0 Source Code from here: http://kigg.codeplex.com/releases/view/53838

First when I try to run/re-built the project I get 3 error messages like this:

```
Error    101    The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Routing\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Routing.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll'    c:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\Kigg\Kigg_3a9b436eace5\Source\Web\Views\Membership\Detail.aspx    21    Kigg.Web
Error    102    The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Routing\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Routing.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll'    c:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\Kigg\Kigg_3a9b436eace5\Source\Web\Views\Membership\Detail.aspx    27    Kigg.Web
Error    103    The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Routing\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Routing.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll'    c:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\Kigg\Kigg_3a9b436eace5\Source\Web\Views\Membership\Detail.aspx    34    Kigg.Web
```

Still when I try to run the project I get this error:

```
Line 43:         }
Line 44: 
Line 45: public Database(string connectionString) :
Line 46:             base(connectionString, _defaultContainerName)
Line 47:         {
```

I follow this solution: http://kigg.codeplex.com/discussions/236299

and copied following files from "Views/shared files" to "App_Data"

Now the error changed to this:

```
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\Kigg\Kigg_3a9b436eace5\Source\Web\App_Data\KiGG.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Documents and Settings\NA-PC\Desktop\Kigg\Kigg_3a9b436eace5\Source\Web\App_Data\KiGG.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Source Error:

Line 92:             Check.Argument.IsNotEmpty(userName, "userName");
Line 93:             
Line 94: return DataContext != null ? FindByUserNameQuery.Invoke(DataContext, userName.Trim()) : Database.UserDataSource.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName.Trim());
Line 95:         }
Line 96
```

I created a database using SSMS and this is my connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="KiGGDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|KiGG.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

(I want to install kigg on my local machine)

I followed these steps to create database http://kigg.codeplex.com/releases/view/53838

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first 3 errors:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/557798/visual-studio-2010-compile-asp-net-3-5-website-using-net4s-aspnet-compiler-exe

Answer (score 0):

open the file Kigg.Web.csproj

search for AspNetCompiler, you will find it here

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)\..\Web" />
</Target>
```

added the Tool Path parameter to be like

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)\..\Web" 
ToolPath="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727"/>
</Target>
```

for the database error
change the connection string from

```
<add name="KiGGDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|KiGG.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

to

```
<add name="KiGGDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=KiGG;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```